# Output variation in lInux

Tags: c, linux

In the following program when I pass the argument - "AAAA%6$p" - my output is - AAAA - but when I pass the argument - 'AAAA%6$p' the output shows - AAAA0x41414141 -. My question is how does the quotes make a difference in the output as the single quotes only represent a character. I need an explanation for the different output.
PS: I'm using Linux 32 bit varient.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char buffer[100];
    strncpy(buffer, argv[1], 100);
    printf(buffer);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The single quotes represent an `int` value.

Comment: `printf(buffer)` is interpreting buffer as a format string. To print the actual contents of the string, use `printf("%s\n", buffer)`. That will tell you what the shell actually passed in. Then read up on shell quoting rules to figure out why.

Comment: @WeatherVane Perhaps if they were in the C program, but this appears to be from the commandline, so most likely we're dealing with bash

Comment: @ChristianGibbons yes of course - but it is a common misconception that `'A'` is `char` type.

Comment: Rule 1: Never pass a string-valued variable (such as `argv[1]`, here copied to the intermediate variable `buffer`) as the first argument to `printf`.  You can't tell how it will behave, since it might contain `%` characters, and if it does, `printf` will try to fetch additional arguments, which you probably didn't provide.  If you want to print an arbitrary string with `printf`, always use something like `printf("%s\n", buffer)`.

Comment: In any bourne or korn shells, quotes are treated differently. Inside a double quote, `$p` will be treated as a variable but inside a single quote they are literal `$` and `p`.

Comment: In summary `printf("AAAA%6");` and `printf("AAAA%6$p");` will have different output. Using string formatter will show the obvious difference. As @SteveSummit has mentioned, the string buffer is used as formatter.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do on how the shell expand the  `$p` variable for double and single quoted strings, and has nothing to do with your program:

```
[gwidion@powergrid ~]$ export p="0x4141"
[gwidion@powergrid ~]$ echo "$p"
0x4141
[gwidion@powergrid ~]$ echo '$p'
$p
```